# Error JAVA0000 -Type android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver is defined multiple times:

Tags: maui

I have the following bug, it happens when I try to run my .NET MAUI application on my android device or any other android device, I don't know why it happens and much less I don't know why it happens, I have updated my packages I have restarted my app.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   JAVA0000    Error in obj\Release\net7.0-android\lp\110\jl\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver.class:
> Type android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver is defined multiple times: obj\Release\net7.0-android\lp\110\jl\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver.class, obj\Release\net7.0-android\lp\20\jl\bin\classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver.class
> Compilation failed
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Release\net7.0-android\lp\110\jl\classes.jar
> android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver.class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6kAc.png)

Comment: You can clean the obj and bin folder and rebuild the project again.

Comment: I tried that multiple times and it didn't work.

Comment: It caused by many reasons, and you can report it as an issue on the Github.